# is it possible to change the voice of these sentences?

Tags: grammar

I don't know if it is possible to change the voice of optatative and exclamatory sentence.

What are the passive form of these sentences 
Suppose:

> 1. go to the shop
> 2. Hurrah! we have won the game!

Comment: The first sentence is imperative, not optative. Optative would be something like "Long live the queen!" or "May he live forever!"

Answer (score 3):

Your first sentance can't really be put into the passive voice. The closest I can think of is something like "The shop must be gone to!", but this is not something any native speaker would actually say, and it requires adding a modal verb anyway.

However, your second sentence can easily be put into the passive voice:

> Hurrah! **The game has been won** (by us)!